# PHP Regexp Assistance

Tags: php

I'm having problems converting HTML into regular expressions.

I just can't seem to figure it out, does anybody know of a good set of tutorials?

This is the code I need to convert:

```
<div class="offerbox_right">
<h2><a href="none.php" target="_blank">NEEDED/(.*?)</a></h2>
<div class="voucher_detail">
<div class="code_wrapper">
<div class="code_left">Code</div>
<span class="code" id="code" title="none.php">NEEDED/(.*?)<img class="scissors" src="none.png" alt="Image" /></span>
</div> <!-- /code_wrapper -->
<p>NEEDED/(.*?)</p>
</div>
```

This is the code I'm using currently and it works great, but I just can't seem to convert it all:

```
if(preg_match_all("/<span\s.*?class=\"code\"[^>]+>(.*?)<img\s.*?class=\"scissors\"[^>]+>/i", $printable, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER));
{
foreach($matches as $match){

echo("$match<br />");

}
}
```

Any help would be great, Thanks!

**EDIT:** I need to echo the **3** match's listed above.

Comment: It seemed to work :P I'm not the greatest programmer.

Comment: This website is *literally* full of questions like your's: How can I parse HTML with regex? - The answer is, as always: You can't, and you shouldn't try. Please, [use a DOM parser](http://www.google.com/search?&q=php+html+regex+domdocument+site%3Astackoverflow.com).

Comment: I have a working modal that I want to use (above) I'm just looking for help with converting the given HTML, Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `echo("$match<br />");` instead of `$match[1]` ,because of the foreach

Comment: So,does this fix the problem?

Comment: Outputting the info wasn't the problem, I need help converting the extra HTML i'm using.